# Meaning of "кагбе пыщъ"?

Tags: значения, сленг

What does this mean?

> "короче кагбе пыщъ"

As I asked a remote developer about delivery of my app project. Never heard anything more from him. Hope it is not a deadly decease.

Comment: I think it very much makes sense to be informed that this is very non-standard usage, deliberate deviation of normal language (but the meaning is as described in Taosique's answer)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's in [Upyachka](https://upyachka.io/) slang. Literally translated that would roughly evaluate into something like *well, sorta kaboom.* Provided your context I guess that would mean he had sent you something, or something bad happened, or he just decided to disappear forever. Anyways, I would consider unprofessional sending something like that with any intent.

"короче" – a common parasite word in Russian, equivalent to *"well, ..."*

"кагбе" – meaning *"sort of"* distorted "как бы", from Upyachka slang.

"пыщь" – something like explosion *"kaboom, bang"*, again from Upyachka slang.

*Upyachka* was a popular website and netlore associated with it in 2000s. The content posted on that website consisted mostly of meaningless meme pictures and GIFs, deliberately misspelled and nonsensical Russian words etc. The most known phrase in Upyachkan, illustrating its characteristic extensive usage of uppercase and exclamation marks was:

> ЖЫВТОНЕ ЧОЧО УПЯЧКА!!! УПЯЧКА УПЯЧКА! ШЯЧЛО ПОПЯЧТСА ПОПЯЧТСА! Я идиот! Убейте меня, кто-нибудь!

Comment: Don't forget about `пыщь я бэтмен` which completely ruins the statistics of any survey: [bash.im](http://bash.im/quote/414397).

Comment: "Well, sorta kaboom" - блестящий перевод! Обожаю такие находки переводчиков, когда вот прямо в яблочко, что называется)